# Chat Widget No Longer Shows in Firefox (ESR) - Did Something Change?

Tags: support, comments, chat

I have Firefox 52.9 [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Extended_Support_Release) and tonight I cannot find any way to enter "chat". Specifically, I was helping on *[Getting a memory leak when signing aChar in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549425/getting-a-memory-leak-when-signing-achar-in-c/51549582?noredirect=1#comment90068596_51549582)* and could not find a way to invoke chat to further help this individual.

[image]
(The link is good until 2018-08-02)

I thought it was a reputation problem, but I have been faced with that before and as soon as the user had 20 (which he had 2 upvotes here), chat was available (no cross-Stack Exchange site hourly sync required). Then looking further, I also noticed (may have been a day or two ago), the "Chat" bar and "people chatting" disappeared off the Stack Overflow main questions page.

Did a JavaScript requirement for chat change recently? I have never allowed google-analytics, quantserve, or scorecardresearch and I have never had a problem with chat before. But tonight, no matter how many comments were posted, I was never given the opportunity to "Avoid Extended Discussions/Open in Chat".

I can't think of what more information may be helpful, but I'm happy to provide further information if it will help. I'm also happy to upload the image here if wanted (it was already put on openSUSE paste as part of the conversation in that question, so it wasn't duplicated here as other than showing something "not there" doesn't add much).

Comment: There's conditions for the near-the-comment-box shortcut appearing, including a lot of back-and-forth between the same two users.  I don't remember the details, but it's possible you didn't hit it for some reason (maybe not @-ing the other user?)

Comment: Ok, thank you for looking, after 4 years here, that was the only time I can remember it not being available. I'll let you know on the next question I get into a significant number of comments whether the comments become available there. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW I saw the link to move comments to chat show up in a comment exchange I was having yesterday. It seems unlikely they've removed it in the past day with no notice, though I'm not sure why you wouldn't have seen it in this case.

Comment: FYI there is a Firefox 60 ESR now, as well; I would recommend upgrading if possible.

Comment: This is opensuse Leap 42.3 -- they only offer 52.9 (for which I am very grateful, 60 no longer renders Gtk+2 themes and I have a lot of problems with the Gtk+3 input widget size causing form difficulties)